# How to change SMB user in windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, user-accounts, samba, smb

I just changed my username account in my laptop, But when I tried to connect my smb client on my another device, I had to login using my old username.

How to change login username?

Comment: You have to change the local account username to match the account on the SMB Windows machine [acting smb server] you are connecting to too. I assume this is a workgroup type setup and you merely need to have the usernames and passwords setup on each machine you connect to via smb if using a Windows machine as a SMB file hosting server.

Answer (score 14):

You can override stored credentials for shares in Windows via the credential manager.
[image]

[image]

Under Windows Credentials:

- If the server in question has an entry, delete it.
- Select Add a Windows Credential.
- Enter the server (e.g. \\IP address\Share).
- Enter new desired credentials.

Navigating manually to \\IP address\Share, it will not use the old credentials any more.

Comment: True, of course.... `net use /delete *`. I don't GUI much.

Comment: Thank You... :)

Answer (score 1):

if you just renamed you username
you have to use the old username and no way to use new name for that

if you made an other user for your laptop
you have to enter new users login in smb login window

Comment: Thank You... :)